# Map of AtomicInteger

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to implement a shared object for calculation of statistics of executions of operations.
Objects state will be represented by `Map<String,AtomicInteger>`(key is the name of operation, value is the number of times the operation was executed). Am I correct that I can choose a `HashMap<String,AtomicInteger>` implementation and use no synchronization on it for getting values from it since AtomicInteger has a volatile `value` field underneath it.

Sample of code that does addition and incrementation of execution stats:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public final class Stats {

private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> statistics = new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

public int increment(String operationName) {
    if (!statistics.containsKey(operationName)) {
        synchronized (statistics) {
            if (!statistics.containsKey(operationName)) 
                statistics.put(operationName, new AtomicInteger(0));
        }
    }

    return statistics.get(operationName).getAndIncrement();
}

public int getOpStats(String operationName) {
    if (!statistics.containsKey(operationName)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return statistics.get(operationName).get();
}

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to ask. Please, try to formulate an specific question.

Comment: There is no need to implement this yourself, a threadsafe mapping from key -> int already exists in Guava's [ConcurrentHashMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be thread safe with regards to *counter initialization* you should use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and always instanciate-and-increase the counters this way:

```
themap.putIfAbsent("the name", new AtomicInteger(0)); 
themap.get("the name").incrementAndGet();
```

You could also make sure you initialize all the counters used before you start, and just use whatever collection you like. A plain `AtomicInteger[]`-array is by far quickest, given that you know where to look, `HashTable` could be slightly quicker than `HashMap`.

If you know on beforehand which counters you have, you could also define a java `enum` of all the counter names and use an `EnumMap<YourCountersEnum, AtomicInteger>`. This would probably give look-up performance close to an `AtomicInteger[]`-array lookup.

Comment: If you do it this way, you'll have to make sure that you putIfAbsent an AtomicInteger(1) not 0!

Comment: @Voo No! If you do that you get 2 the first time you initialize a counter. You always increment them unconditionally by incrementAndGet, but creates them if they was null. "null == zero". Bit me as well.

Comment: Ah ok, yes obviously you can always create the AtomicInteger if you want and it's probably not going to be especially expensive - still seems rather wasteful, but yes will work.

Comment: putIfAbsent is cheaper if the object exists already. Increasing a number is not that expensive (that's why it has a method). It's the two volatile lookups that are expensive here.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better? `x = putIfAbsent(..., new AtomicInteger(1)); if (x != null) x.incrementAndGet();`

Comment: It would introduce a race condition.